# Regex only for alphanumeric not for numbers

Tags: regex, r

I want to match "3 T1F ROHITE01WMILWWI16" which contains only caps letter and numbers nothing else. The condition is that it ,must be both. It should not return true for all alphabetic and all numeric.

Test cases:

- 3 T1F ROHITE01WMILWI16
- 3 T1F ROHITE01WMILwI16
- 3 T1F ROHITE01WMIL.I16
- 1234
- aaaa
- T1F ROHITH01WMILWI16

I am using ^[0-9  A-Z]+$ it matches correctly the first and last test case but also returns true for fourth test case i.e 1234.

Comment: Nothing else? What about the spaces, dots? Which test cases are valid and which are not? What is the minimum string length? Try [`^[0-9 A-Z]*[A-Z][0-9 A-Z]*[0-9][0-9 A-Z]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/fW6dG2/1) that will require at least 2 characters.

Comment: See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/BZaJVx) - is it what you are after?

Comment: Spaces are their no problem with that, it can be anywhere in string. Dot i used to check as a test case.

Comment: It worked. Thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: I posted one more solution just in case :)

Comment: You can use [`^(?=\D*\d)[ \d]*[A-Z][ A-Z\d]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/fA4fQ4/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^([0-9 A-Z]*[A-Z][0-9 A-Z]*[0-9][0-9 A-Z]*|[0-9 A-Z]*[0-9][0-9 A-Z]*[A-Z][0-9 A-Z]*)$
```

It matches

- `^` - start of string

  Then come *two alternatives*. *Alternative 1*:
- `[0-9 A-Z]*` - 0+ allowed characters
- `[A-Z]` - one uppercase ASCII letter (obligatory subpattern)
- `[0-9 A-Z]*` - 0+ allowed characters
- `[0-9]` - a digit
- `[0-9 A-Z]*`  - 0+ allowed characters

  *Alternative 2* is the same as above but the digit and uppercase letter character classes are swaped to match `1A` or `A1` strings.
- `$` - end of string

Thus, the *minimum required string length is 2 characters*.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fW6dG2/2) and the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/BZaJVx):

```
s <- c("3 T1F ROHITE01WMILWI16", "3 T1F ROHITE01WMILwI16", "3 T1F ROHITE01WMIL.I16", "1234", "aaaa", "T1F ROHITH01WMILWI16")
grep("^[0-9 A-Z]*[A-Z][0-9 A-Z]*[0-9][0-9 A-Z]*$", s, value=TRUE)
```

If you need to support strings of any length, use [this PCRE regex](https://regex101.com/r/fN1jQ6/1):

```
^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])[0-9 A-Z]*$
```

The `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` lookahead requires at least one uppercase letter and `(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])` requires one digit.

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/fuSDfK):

```
s <- c("3 T1F ROHITE01WMILWI16", "3 T1F ROHITE01WMILwI16", "3 T1F ROHITE01WMIL.I16", "1234", "aaaa", "T1F ROHITH01WMILWI16")
grep("^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])[0-9 A-Z]*$", s, perl=TRUE, value=TRUE)
```

Comment: Your non lookahead version [does not match `1A`](https://regex101.com/r/nB5dM6/1).

Comment: @bobblebubble:  You are right. That is why I posted the lookahead one: I felt there might be some more scenarios. I updated the answer and the demo links.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the now deleted answer by @akrun, you can look for strings that contain both uppercase letters and numeric characters (with or without spaces) and that don't contain any other characters:

```
str1 <- c("3 T1F MILWWIHE01WMILWWI16", "3 T1F ROHITE01WMILWI16", "3 T1F ROHITE01WMILwI16", "3 T1F ROHITE01WMIL.I16", "1234", "aaaa", "T1F ROHITH01WMILWI16")

str1[grepl("[A-Z ]+", str1) & grepl("[0-9 ]+", str1) & !grepl("[^A-Z0-9 ]", str1)]
# [1] "3 T1F MILWWIHE01WMILWWI16" "3 T1F ROHITE01WMILWI16"    "T1F ROHITH01WMILWI16"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lookahead:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9 A-Z]+$

str1 <- c("3 T1F MILWWIHE01WMILWWI16", "3 T1F ROHITE01WMILWI16", "3 T1F ROHITE01WMILwI16", "3 T1F ROHITE01WMIL.I16", "1234", "aaaa", "T1F ROHITH01WMILWI16")

grep("^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9 A-Z]+$", str1, perl=TRUE, value=TRUE)
# [1] "3 T1F MILWWIHE01WMILWWI16" "3 T1F ROHITE01WMILWI16"    "T1F ROHITH01WMILWI16"
```

Comment: Thx, I've modified the regex.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Cath